# Is the type field in NDEF records required?

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

If I am writing or reading a NDEF record on a tag, do I need to include the Type field? Can readers still read/write it?

**UPDATE**

Apparently one of the types is 0x05 "Unknown." The Type field is empty, so it does what I need it to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No. Some record types require the Type field, some do not. The ones who require:

- External type
- Mime Media
- Absolute URI
- All well-known types

The ones who forbid:

- Unknown type
- Empty record

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to know the Type while Reading and Writing on a tag.

For Reading, you need to specify the following 3 parameters: NFC connection descriptor, Buffer to store the data read & Buffer size.

For Writing, you need to know the NFC connection descriptor, NDEF data to write and Length of the data.

Comment: In the case of writing to a card, the TYPE would be included in the NDEF data. And for reading, the TNF and TYPE must be included but does not have to be known ahead of time. My original question was wondering if the TYPE field was required in a NDEF message. If you use a unknown TYPE, (Type Name Field = 0x5 or 101 in binary) then the TYPE field is left "blank," it isn't included.